# Creating dynamic x-axis labels when using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot which uses facets as shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
           ep = c("r1", "r2", "r1", "r2"),
           val = c(3, 5, 2, 5),
           suffix = c("_w", "_x", "_y", "_z"))

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ep, y = val, fill = ep)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~grp)
```

[image]

I would like to append the suffix column to each of the x-axis labels, so that end result would look like this:

[image]

I have tried this approach below, but it is saying that the suffix variable cannot be found:

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ep, y = val, fill = ep)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) paste0(x, suffix)) +
  facet_wrap(~grp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do it within ggplot, create the suffix column first.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                  ep = c("r1", "r2", "r1", "r2"),
                  val = c(3, 5, 2, 5),
                  suffix = c("_w", "_x", "_y", "_z"))

dat %>% 
  mutate(x_suffix = paste0(ep, suffix)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x_suffix, y = val, fill = ep)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~grp, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Could you explain what your solution does? Does it apply also if I want to have a different label based on table()?